# How to integrate Google tasks in evolution 3.12

Tags: xubuntu, evolution, 14.10

Evolution 3.12 is said to support Google tasks, but how? I use Xubuntu, so no Gnome Online Accounts, as far as I see.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to use a GNOME Online Account for your Evolution to integrate with Google Tasks. According to Milan Crha, who completed the Evolution integration with Google Tasks:

On Tue, 2014-11-18 at 06:40 +0100, Milan Crha wrote:

> Evolution cannot authenticate using OAuth on its own, 
>   it handles only user+password authentication requests (it can ask for a
>   password only), but the Google tasks require OAuth, thus the only way 
>   is to use GNOME Online Accounts (GOA) and enable the Calendar part. If 
>   any user had already created a GOA account, then it might also need to 
>   re-authenticate it, because the OAuth key has a bit flag which 
>   services are enabled and the Google tasks had been added in time of 
>   the feature being added into evolution-data-server. There is also 
>   needed certain libgdata version (0.15.1 or later).
>
> Feel free to use this answer in the Ubuntu forum

On Tue, 2014-11-18 at 07:07 +0100, Milan Crha wrote:

> On Tue, 2014-11-18 at 01:00 -0500, Matthew wrote:
>
> > ```
> >     It seems strange that Google Tasks require OAuth, but
> > ```
> >
> > Evolution can access Google Calendar without OAuth.
>
> there are used different protocols. Calendar uses CalDAV, while Google 
>   Tasks uses libgdata, because the tasks cannot be accessed using CalDAV.
>           Bye,
>           Milan

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers my question. Is there a way to use GOA in Xubuntu?